# Memory Leak - WCF Exception

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, memory-leaks, ninject

My ASP.NET MVC3 application uses Ninject to instantiate service instances through a wrapper.  The controller's constructor has an IMyService parameter and the action methods call myService.SomeRoutine().  The service (WCF) is accessed over SSL with a wsHttpBinding.

I have a search routine that can return so many results that it exceeds the maximum I have configured in WCF (Maximum number of items that can be serialized or deserialized in an object graph).  When this happens, the application pools for both the service and the client grow noticeably and remain bloated well past the end of the request.

I know that I can restrict the number of results or use DTOs to reduce the amount of data being transmitted.  That said, I want to fix what appears to be a memory leak.

Using [CLR Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16273), I see that the bulk of the heap is used by the following:

- System.RunTime.IOThreadTimer.TimerManager
- System.RunTime.IOThreadTimer.TimerGroup
- System.RunTime.IOThreadTimer.TimerQueue
- System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionServerSettings
- System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener
- System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpsChannelListener
- System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory
- System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder
- System.Runtime.SynchronizedPool
- System.Runtime.SynchronizedPool.Entry[]
- ...TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.TextBufferedMessageWriter
- System.Runtime.SynchronizedPool.GlobalPool
- System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferManagerOutputStream
- System.Byte[][]
- System.Byte[] (92%)

In addition, if I modify the search routine to return an empty list (while the NHibernate stuff still goes on in the background - verified via logging), the application pool sizes remain unchanged.  If the search routine returns significant results without an exception, the application pool sizes remain unchanged.  I believe the leak occurs when the list of objects is serialized and results in an exception.

I upgraded to the newest Ninject and I used log4net to verify that the service client was closed or aborted depending on its state (and the state was never faulted).  The only thing I found interesting was that the service wrapper was being finalized and not explicitly disposed.

I'm having difficulty troubleshooting this to find out why my application pools aren't releasing memory in this scenario.  What else should I be looking at?

**UPDATE:** Here's the binding...

```
<wsHttpBinding>
 <binding name="wsMyBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" 
  receiveTimeout="00:02:00" sendTimeout="00:02:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
  transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
  maxBufferPoolSize="999999" maxReceivedMessageSize="99999999" 
  messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="false" 
  allowCookies="false">
  <readerQuotas maxDepth="90" maxStringContentLength="99999" 
  maxArrayLength="99999999" maxBytesPerRead="99999" 
  maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
  <reliableSession enabled="false" />
  <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
   <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
  </security>
 </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

**UPDATE #2**: Here is the Ninject binding but more curious is the error message.  My wrapper wasn't setting MaxItemsInObjectGraph properly so it used the default.  Once I set this, the leak went away.  Seems that the client and service keep the serialized/deserialized data in memory when the service sends the serialized data to the client and the client rejects it because it exceeds MaxItemsInObjectGraph.

**Ninject Binding:**

```
Bind<IMyService>().ToMethod(x => 
    new ServiceWrapper<IMyService>("MyServiceEndpoint")
    .Channel).InRequestScope();
```

**Error Message:**

> The InnerException message was 'Maximum number of items that can be
>   serialized or deserialized in an object graph is '**65536**'

This doesn't actually fix the memory leak so I am still curious as to what have been causing it if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: What binding do you use for the wrapper?

Comment: @Remo: I added the binding above - thanks!

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. I meant the Ninject Binding used to create the wrapper. Especially the scope is of interest.

Comment: With this binding the wrapper should be disposed at the end of the MVC request if you are using Ninject and Ninject.MVC2 Version >= 2.2

Answer (score 1):

How are you handling your proxy client creation and disposal?

I've found the most common cause of WCF-related memory leaks is mishandling WCF proxy clients.

I suggest at the very least wrapping your clients with a `using` block kinda like this:

```
using (var client = new WhateverProxyClient())
{
  // your code goes here
}
```

This ensures that the client is properly closed and disposed of, freeing memory.

This method is a bit controversial though, but it should remove the possibility of leaking memory from client creation.

Take a look [here](http://omaralzabir.com/do-not-use-using-in-wcf-client/) for more on this topic.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  The service wrapper has a dispose and finalize that both ensure the client is closed/aborted before it is set to null (using code similar to that article).  I think I will create a test harness to try out variations of this scenario to try and isolate the leak.  Way too many variables right now.

Comment: -1: since you know about that article, why would you suggest anyone use a `using` block?